# What is U2FsdGVkX1?

Tags: encryption, implementation, 3des

Using [CryptoJS 3.1](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#Encoders) I noticed that using 3Des, the encrypted message always start with

> U2FsdGVkX1

Why is the first part of the encryption always the same?

What information does this hold and how does that information become `U2FsdGVkX1`?

Comment: Your question aside, the fact that the *default, easiest* way of using block ciphers in CryptoJS is ECB mode is an irresponsibly catastrophic API design choice.

Comment: @StephenTouset My (by now sizable) experience is that using algorithm defaults in a cryptographic library is *always* problematic. CBC would have been better, but by now I would recomment an authenticated cipher. It's simply better to have the programmer make concious decissions instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is:

> Why do the encrypted files always start with "Salted__" ("U2FsdGVkX1" in base64)? Isn't giving away information like this insecure?

> The encrypted files must always start with "Salted__" to interoperate with OpenSSL. OpenSSL expects this. The 8 bytes that spell "Salted__" are always immediately followed by another random 8 bytes of salt. The encrypted stream starts at the 17th byte. This way, even if you use the same password to encrypt 2 different files, the actual secret keys used to encrypt these 2 files are very different.

> It is possible to omit the salt, but this is highly discouraged

source: [http://juliusdavies.ca/commons-ssl/pbe.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20161130092304/http://juliusdavies.ca/commons-ssl/pbe.html)

Comment: And just for completeness (since the quote only answers half of the question) starting the files with "Salted__" does not give away information beyond the fact that the file was encrypted with (or at least for) OpenSSL, which is assumed to not be secret. So it isn't insecure.